# VBA run macro on cell change?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code and function that is supposed to run when the user types/pastes into a cell.

```
'Insert Depot Memo Data for user
 Dim oCell As Range, targetCell As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo Message
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only if a value in column I has changed
        If Not GetWb("Depot Memo", ws2) Then Exit Sub

        With ws2
            For Each targetCell In Target
                Set oCell = .Range("J1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=targetCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not oCell Is Nothing Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 1)
                     targetCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = oCell.Offset(0, -2)

                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
```

Function:

```
Function GetWb(wbNameLike As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    For Each Wb In Workbooks
        If Wb.Name Like "*" & wbNameLike & "*" Then '<-- check if workbook name contains "Depot Memo"
            Set ws = Wb.Worksheets(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetWb = Not ws Is Nothing
End Function
```

This code works, but it is not launching correctly. As soon as the user types/pastes a value into the cell (once the cell has changed) the code is supposed to run.

At the moment, the code is not working unless the user escapes the cell and then goes back to click on it.

I have this code under a private worksheet selection change event. I don't know if this is right? When i try to put it under a private worksheet change event it doesn't do anything.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should look into the worksheet change event see http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by checking Worksheet_Change. Provided below is an example which will check cells of a range. In this example A1:C10.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You want this under the `Worksheet_Change` event handler.

The `Worksheet_SelectionChage` event fires only when, as you observe, the user changes the physical *selection* on the worksheet.

The `Change` event fires whenever any cell *changes* (some limitations to this).